# Replace unknown number of same characters

Tags: reporting-services, replace

I am getting passed multiple parameters to SSRS from a third party application.  Unfortunately, this third party app places equal signs "=" in front of each parameter that is passed.  I need to strip the equal signs from the front of the parameters.

Example of parameters:

```
=HYDRO, =OKE, =OKS, =TRANSLOC, =TECHMIC, etc.
```

I will never know how many parameters are sent only that at least one will be sent.  I have the expression:

```
=Replace(Parameters!SiteIDParam.Value(0),"=","")
```

That successfully strips the first instance of the equal sign, but not any of the others (if there are others).  Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Where do you need to use the parameter values? In the header? Body? A dataset query? A property? Can you help us repro your scenario?

Comment: Also, it's a bit unclear what you mean by "multiple parameters", because you need to specifiy up front in an RDL which parameters will be accepted. Did you in fact mean a multi-valued parameter?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  The parameters are in the primary dataset query for the report.  For example:  This parameter is named SiteIDParam.  It is passed a parameter than can have multiple values.  Unfortunately, these parameters, regardless of how many there are, will have the equal sign in front of them.  So, no matter how many parameters are passed, I need to strip the equal sign ("=") from the front of that parameter.

Comment: A quick fix / workaround may then include changing you're query from `WHERE xyz IN (@SiteIDParam)` to something along the lines of `WHERE '='+xyz IN (@SiteIDParam)`.

Comment: Have you tried "cleaning" your parameters using a custom function?

Comment: No, Sebastien, I have not tried cleaning my parameters.  That may be what I need to do, but I have no idea how to do that.  If you could help with that, that would be great.

Comment: Jeroen, trying your suggestion now.

Comment: Jeroen, trying your suggestion now.  UPDATE - Produces an error:  "Cannot read the next data row for the dataset. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow) ORA-01722: invalid number.  I believe the answer is going to be cleaning the parameters using a custom function.